# Own PHP DI/IoC Container with parameters/arguments

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, containers, ioc-container

I'm making my own framework for practice and I'm stuck with DI/IoC container, with sending parameters in constructor.

**Container.php**

```
class Container
{
    private $registry = array();
    private $shared = array();

    public function set($name, Closure $resolve)
    {
        if (!$this->exists($name)) {
            $this->registry[$name] = $resolve;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Class with name ' . $name . ' is already registered.');
        }
    }

    public function get($name, $arguments = array())
    {
        if (!$this->exists($name, 'shared')) {
            $this->shared[$name] = $this->getNew($name, $arguments);
        }

        return $this->shared[$name];
    }

    public function getNew($name, $arguments = array())
    {
        if ($this->exists($name, 'registry')) {
            $class = $this->registry[$name];
            return $class();
        }

        throw new Exception('Class with name ' . $name . ' does not exist.');
    }

    private function exists($name, $type = 'registry')
    {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->$type);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$container = new Container;

$container->set('file', function() {
    return new Application\Library\File();
});

$container->set('cache', function($path, $type = 'json') use ($container) {
    return new Application\Library\Cache($container->get('file'), $path, $type);
});

$params = array (
    'path/to/cache/',
    'json'
);
$cache = $container->get('cache', $params);
```

Question is: how can i send parameters/arguments with **get()** or **getNew()** method to constructor. I saw **ReflectionClass($classname)** and **newInstanceArgs($args)** but I don't know how to use it and where to put it.

EDIT - Maybe something like this:

```
public function getNew($name, $arguments = array())
{
    if ($this->exists($name, 'registry')) {
        if (count($arguments) > 0) {
            $object = new ReflectionClass($name);
            return $object->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
        } else {
            $class = $this->registry[$name];
            return $class();
        }
    }

    throw new Exception('Class with name ' . $name . ' does not exist.');
}
```

But it does not work because for creating **Cache** class I inject only 2 of 3 parameters with **$container->get()** and $params array. First parameter is fixed in **$container->set(**) with **File** class and it does not inject properly with instance creation. Is there any solution ?

Error:
*Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Library\Cache::__construct() must be an instance of Application\Library\File, string given*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution that works but I'm not happy with it:

```
public function getNew($name, $arguments = array())
{
    if ($this->exists($name, 'registry')) {
        $class = $this->registry[$name];
        $count = count($arguments);
        switch ($count) {
            case 1:
                $object = $class($arguments[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                $object = $class($arguments[0], $arguments[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                $object = $class($arguments[0], $arguments[1], $arguments[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                $object = $class($arguments[0], $arguments[1], $arguments[2], $arguments[3]);
                break;
            default:
                $object = $class();
                break;
        }
        return $object;
    }

    throw new Exception('Class with name ' . $name . ' does not exist.');
}
```

Counts number of $arguments, going through switch case and return instance of $classname with injected arguments.